# #1054 - Unknown column 'tbl_ads.DATE_CREATED' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

I need to update this table in MySQL. See below:

```
UPDATE `bazargar_adcsrpt`.`tbl_specials`
SET `IS_SHOWN`= 2 
WHERE `tbl_ads`.`DATE_CREATED`= '2016-05-07 15:14:06' AND `tbl_ads`.`ID` = `tbl_specials`.`ADS_ID`
```

What query will do this? I'm thinking a join but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with `tbl_ads`.

```
UPDATE `bazargar_adcsrpt`.`tbl_specials`
JOIN tbl_ads ON `tbl_ads`.`ID` = `tbl_specials`.`ADS_ID`
SET `IS_SHOWN`= 2 
WHERE `tbl_ads`.`DATE_CREATED`= '2016-05-07 15:14:06'
```